# Is it possible to not allow null values for particular in an excel data entry spreadsheet (VBA?)?

Tags: excel, vba, validation, rows, spreadsheet

I have an excel worksheet where I have a number of manual data entry and calculated columns, which is to be filled in line by line with the rows filled from left to right.

I have a few columns which I want to ensure are not left blank as this data entry is carried out.

E.g.
[image: Example data entry sheet]

Here I am entering data from left to right on the 3rd row and want to ensure that if the person doing the data entry manually accidentally skips the "Unique ID" column and tries to fill in "Type" first, they will be forced back to the "Unique ID" cell or at least experience a pop-up to tell them to enter in "Unique ID" first.

Is this something that can be done?

Comment: Yes, doable with the Worksheet.Change event.

Comment: Great, do you have a suggestion of how to implement this?

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change) as well as examples here on SO should be pretty helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This can be handled in different ways; one of which is adding a simple data validation rule.

Add a data validation rule to the 2nd cell that checks whether or not the prior field is blank.  If so, don't allow entry in the cell and display a pop-up message.
Data validation rules just have to have a a TRUE result.

Add this formula to a custom data validation rule on the 2nd cell.

```
not(isblank(c7))
```

[image]

Then, if the user tries to populate the 2nd cell while the 1st is still blank, the user gets an alert message and then the cell contents is cleared.

[image]

UPDATE #1

If you need to create a dependency for a data validation list you could add a table to a new sheet to act as your list handler. The basic theory is that one column is filled with an index of each row, a 2nd column checks to see if the criteria has been met, a 3rd column contains every item that could appear in the list and a 4th column is a formula that builds the list based on all of the criteria.

Here is a working example.  It's a little different than your scenario but it shows the premise.  The example below builds a list of items that can only be selected once.  Once the item is selected in a cell, it does not appear in the lists for other cells.

[image]

`t_FinalPlans_Medical` is the name of the table.

`medicalRow_FinalPlanSelections` is a named range containing the cells that have the data validation rules/drop-down lists.

`dataValid_FinalMedicalPlans_OptHeading` is a named range holding the column header.

```
INDIRECT("t_FinalPlans_Medical[[#Headers],[Column1]]")
```

`dataValid_FinalMedicalPlans_OptList` is a named range for the index column.

```
INDIRECT("t_FinalPlans_Medical[Index]")
```

Index Column Formula `IF([@[Unselected Plans]]="","",MAX($D$7:D7)+1)`

Final Plan Selections Column
Each cell in this column is manually typed.

Unselected Plans Column Formula

```
IF(COUNTIF(medicalRow_FinalPlanSelections,[@[Final Plan Selections]])=0,[@[Final Plan Selections]],"")
```

Column1 Formula

```
IFERROR(INDEX([Unselected Plans],MATCH(ROW()-ROW(t_FinalPlans_Medical[[#Headers],[Column1]]),[Index],0)),"")
```

Formula used as Data Validation (dynamically expands) `OFFSET(dataValid_FinalMedicalPlans_OptHeading,1,0,MAX(dataValid_FinalMedicalPlans_OptList),1)`

https://trumpexcel.com/excel-drop-down-list/

Comment: Thanks, the issue I have with this is that the next cell is a dropdown list so already has data validation (list) applied. Can I add additional validation rules to this cell to use the method you described?